# Unable to run any yum command on Redhat 7

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I have a new Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3, I am trying to install Ambari Server on this machine by following the steps in the link

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_download_the_ambari_repo_lnx7.html

I am able to run the first step i.e

```
wget -nv http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.1.0/ambari.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo
```

But when I am executing the next steps `yum repolist` or `yum install ambari-server` I am getting the following error.

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager


rhn-plugin: RPM error.  The message was:
Could not determine what version of Red Hat Linux you are running.
If you get this error, try running 

        rpm --rebuilddb
```

I ran the above command but it did not solve my problem. I tried to search for the answer but I did not find anything on the internet.

Can anyone identify this problem?

Comment: What was the result of running `rpm --rbuilddb`? Did the error change or not? What was the output? Were there more errors reported?

Comment: rpm --rbuilddb silently came without any output. Nothing really happened

Comment: Does it work if you remove the Ambari repo? Are you sure it was working before?

Comment: It was not working before Ambari repo also.

Comment: Does any of the logs have more information on what's not working? What have you tried to resolve it, besides running `rpm --rebuilddb`?  Was it a fresh install of the server? Do you know how long or at what point `rpm` broke on that system?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with /var directory which got corrupted. I asked my IT staff rebuild the OS, it started working fine.